# Laravel Вывести количество и связанных моделей по статусам

Tags: laravel, запрос, count, relationship

Есть таблицы:

```
statuses (id, name) - справочник
compamies (id, name)
jobs (id,  company_id)
job_requests (id, job_id, status_id)
```

Нужно подсчитать и вывести количество job_requests по статусам. Достаточно id статуса, имя статуса, и его количество в `job_requests`

Каким вариантом это можно и лучше реализовать, и главное как?

1. Есть связь на уровне модели `$company->jobRequests()`
2. Либо через DB fasade

   $jobRequestsBuilder = DB::table('job_requests')->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'job_requests.job_id')->where('jobs.company_id', '=', $company->id);

А нужно получить массив вида

```
[
["name" => "status_1", "count" => 10, "id" => status1Id],
["name" => "status_2", "count" => 2, "id" => status2Id]
["name" => "status_4", "count" => 4, "id" => status3Id]
]
```

Был такой вариант

$applicantsBuilder = DB::table('job_requests')
->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'job_requests.job_id')
->where('jobs.company_id', '=', $company->id);

```
$statuses = Status::all();

foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    $applicantsBuilder->selectRaw("count(case when status_id = " . $status->id . " then 1 end) as " . $status->name);
}
```

Но так, я получаю, только часть данных

```
{"pending":0,"approved":0,"rejected":0,"shortlisted":0,"reserved":0,"interviewed":0,"selected":0,"hired":0}
```

Как получить id не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Думаю через фасад DB так

```
$statuses = DB::table('job_requests')
    ->leftJoin('statuses', 'job_requests.status_id', '=', 'statuses.id')
    ->selectRaw('statuses.name AS name, count(*) as count, statuses.id AS id')
    ->groupBy('statuses.name')
    ->get();
```

если вариант выше свалиться в ошибку группировки то можно попробовать

```
->groupBy('statuses.name', 'statuses.id')
```